# How to start/stop Websphere Message Broker using Java?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, administration, messagebroker, pcf

I want my J2EE application had ability to programmatically start/stop Websphere Message Broker 7.0.1 or Integration Bus 9. MQ Explorer already have this feature, so i know it's possible to code this in java. What instrument should i use to implement this functionality? I've tried both MQ java API, PCF, CMP API, but didn't find any specific command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CMP API isn't able to do this because there needs to something on the other end already listening to the MQ Queues in order to respond to the CMP message. The toolkit and IBX actually breaks out to the shell from java to start brokers which is why they can only start and stop local brokers

Comment: thank you for your reply! Yes CMP API isn't able to do this. But I doubt that broker explorer and toolkit use ssh connection to server. They are definitely able to start and stop remote brokers(be sure, it's possible, i've done it many times), and there are no ssh credentials neeeded to do this. So i'm still wondering how they manage to do this.

Comment: IBX and toolkit cant stop and start remote Execution Groups (because the Broker is handling the CMP responses) but not remote brokers. The stop and start of a broker is accomplished by breaking out to the lcol shell (not ssh) which is why it only works for local brokers.

Comment: The exception is broker's which are defined as an MQ Service which can be stopped and started by the queue manager. This works because MQ knows the command to execute on the remote system and MQ's tcp listener handles the remote requests. If you had a broker defined as an MQ Service you might be able to use MQ PCF classes.